# locale の発音は？

Tags: 英語

地域化 (L10N) の際に使う情報の名称として locale という英語が使われています。
オイラ的にはこの単語の発音は　ろーかる　なのですが　ろけーる　と発音する人が多いようです。

コンピュータ業界的にはどう発音すればよいでしょうか（日本において・英語圏において）？
コンピュータ業界を離れて一般的にはどう発音するのが普通ですか (ditto) ？

追記
フランス語の形容詞 `local` の女性単数変化 `locale` が語源なら　
英語ネイティブな人にとって　ろぅかーる　（アクセントは「か」）
日本人が考える英語/米語っぽい発音（文字の並びだけ見たとき）が　ろけーる
なのはうなづけます。

オイラが知りたいのはむしろこっちだ。
ろけーる　という発音はどこから/誰から出てきたのでしょうか？
日本の JIS 固有用語なのでしょうか？
なんでこんな怪しい読みが普及しちゃったんでしょう？

Comment: widthでも似たような問題が。ｗ
pj内、チーム内で統一できてれば良い気がしますが...

Comment: 英語ならロカールでカを強く発音します。米国西海岸ならロキャールでキャを強く言いますね。

Comment: ローカルだとlocalと紛らわしいなとも

Comment: ローカルだとlocalと紛らわしいからロケールに決めたって話をどこかで読んだ覚えがありますが・・・　軽くググった範囲ではソースが見つからないので、話半分に聞いておいてください。

Answer (score 11):

元のフランス語を尊重するなら「ロカール」ですが、JIS規格にある「ロケール」が無難かと思います。

Comment: JIS とは！規格マニアの心をくすぐられます。規格書番号や章番号がわかると幸せになれそうな気がします。(ちなみに JIS でなぜ ロケール と称したのかがわかるともっと幸せになれそうです)

Answer (score 10):

[Linux における日本語ロケールに関する指針](http://archive.linux.or.jp/JF/JFdocs/Japanese-Locale-Policy.txt) というドキュメントでは↓のように書いてます。

> この文書におけるロケール(locale)とは、以下に挙げる規格の文化圏固有操作 (locale)を指す。
>
> ・ POSIX.1
>
> ```
> (IEEE 1003.1:1990, ISO/IEC 9945-1:1990s)
> (翻訳規格 JIS X 3030-1994)              
>  ・ Programing Language C
>
> (ISO/IEC 9899:1990)       
> (翻訳規格 JIS X 3010-1993)
>  ・ Programing Language C (Amendment 1)
>
> (ISO/IEC 9899:1990/Amd.1:1995)
> (翻訳規格 JIS X 3010:1996)    
>
> 注): locale という単語の英語本来の発音は「ロケール」というよりはむ
> しろ「ロウカール」のような音である。また「ロカール」と表記されるこ
> ともある。しかし既に「ロケール」という訳語が定着しているため、本文
> 書でも JIS 規格の表記に倣い「ロケール」を使用している。
> ```

これによるとJIS規格の表記が「ロケール」なのだそうです。
英語発音だと「ロウカール」「ロカール」だそうです。